# finding a list item by its index

Tags: python, list

I've started off with this.

```
def month(n):
lst = ['Months','Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
lst.index(x)
```

I need it to work as follows:

```
>>>first = month(1)
>>>first
'Jan'

>>> second = month(11)
>>> second
'Nov'
```

How can this be done?

Comment: 1. start with the most basic tutorial. 2. it's done.

Comment: I still couldn't help pouncing on this one :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def month(n):
 lst = ['Months','Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
 return lst[n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a dictionary?

```
lst = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
months = dict(zip(range(1, 13), lst))
month = months.get
month(1) # Jan
```